# помощь по коду PHP

Tags: php

У меня есть код

```
$mas_inbox["key_words"]="слово,слово2,слово3";
$key_words_mas=explode(',',$mas_inbox["key_words"]);

foreach( $key_words_mas as $key_words_item){
    $key_words_array =array('id_advert'=>$id_advert, 'name_cyrillic'=>$key_words_item,'name_latin'=>encode_key_words($key_words_item));
    $db_query = forming_db_query_indexmas(DB_PREF."advert_key_words",$key_words_array,$operation,"id_advert");
    $q_ident = obr_db_query($db_query);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Принцип работы : массив  ключевых слов ,  каждое ключевое слово заносится в базу ..

Но из моего примера видно , что у меня в базу попадает 3 слова, но  только последнее ключевое слово во всех трех колонках получается(т.е переменная перезаписывается ) .
Подскажите , как грамотно нужно оформить код,чтобы было в каждой колонке разное  слово  ?

Comment: Первый раз вижу функции `forming_db_query_indexmas` и `obr_db_query`.

Comment: Судя по скрину, первое?

Comment: @Visman, это скорее всего `function x()` или `define()`

Comment: Уважаемый автор вопроса. Если один из ответов Вас удовлетворяет, то отметьте его как "Лучший" с помощью галочки под стрелочками для голосования.

Answer (score 2):

Можно увидеть немного больше кода? Хочу понять полную его семантику.
А то вопрос возможно неправильно сформирован.

Я думаю, что Ваши User-defined функции немножко "кривые".

Вот мой вариант. Думаю оно должно выглядеть так:

```
$kw['keywords'] = 'w1,w2,w3';
$w_array = explode(',', $kw['keywords']);

foreach ($w_array as $w_item){
    $latin_kw = encode_key_words($w_item);
    $insert = $mysqli->query("insert into keywords values (null, '{$id_advert}', '{$w_item}', '{$latin_w}')");
}
```

[Песочница](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cb34f269bbddd63973c739f1a05156378bbcc4cb)